# "configuration files" issue when trying to run Ultimaker Cura on RPI 4

Tags: ultimaker-cura, raspberry-pi

I have installed Cura on my RPI 4 by using the "sudo apt-get install cura" terminal command.

Whenever I try to run the application, however, I get this:

[image: Cura running on RPI crashes]

Is there something wrong with the configuration files? I have tried clicking the "Backup and reset configuration", and even deleting the configuration files folder. But it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The regular version of Cura has system requirements that the Raspberry Pi cannot meet, including the GPU required to run it.

However, it looks like you can try an experimental version of Cura [**here**](https://community.ultimaker.com/topic/28746-experimental-cura-build-for-raspberry-pi-4-now-available/).